# Play audio clips on mobile and tablet browsers

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following code to play audio clips upon the click of an image.
It works on desktop, but not on mobile or tablet browsers, how can I get it to work on them?

```
var sounds = [


"AUDIO URL",
"AUDIO URL",
"AUDIO URL",
"AUDIO URL",


          ],
oldSounds = [];

var playSounds = function () {
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sounds.length)),
    thisSound = sounds[index];

    oldSounds.push(thisSound);
    sounds.splice(index, 1);

    if (sounds.length < 1) {
        sounds = oldSounds.splice(0, oldSounds.length);
    }

    $("#element").html("<embed src=\"" + thisSound + "\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" />");
}
```

Comment: You are using `embed` but I think you should use `audio` tag instead.

Comment: How do I do that? I tried replacing embed with audio but the sound didn't work.

Comment: Use ``autoplay`` instead of ``autostart``, along with ``<audio>`` instead of ``<embed>``.

Comment: This is the code I'm using jsfiddle.net/adamsears/kZF9T - which won't work on mobile/tablet

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [you can use](http://caniuse.com/#search=audio) the HTML [audio tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-audio-element):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
</body>
</html>
```

You can check a live example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio).

**Edit**

So change your last line with:

```
$("#element").html("<audio autoplay><source src=\"" + thisSound + "\" type=\"audio\/mp4\"><\/audio>");
```

Comment: What code would I use instead of what I'm using at the moment then? This is what I'm using now - 
`<a onclick="playSounds()">
    <img src="IMAGE URL" id="ImageButton1">
</a>`

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea what it could be.

Comment: Is your audio file compatible with your device?